# Hive sql over partition

Tags: sql, hive

I've have a column for row_number() over (partition...)

```
row_number() OVER (partition BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date, order_number) AS order_row,
```

and another column which calculates "cumulative" spend using over (partition...)

```
sum(spend_amount) OVER (partition BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date, order_number) as cumulative_spend,
```

how can I flag in another column which order_row had reach $100 first? which is order_number 123458, order_row = 3 for $110.00, is the one I want to flag.

eg.

```
customer_number    order_date  order_number  spend_amount order_row  cumulative_spend
abcdefg            01/01/2023  123456        10.00        1          10.00
abcdefg            01/01/2023  123457        50.00        2          60.00
abcdefg            14/01/2023  123458        50.00        3          110.00
abcdefg            23/01/2023  123459        20.00        4          130.00
```

I tried the following but not quite what I was expecting, I want to see nulls and then 1, 2, 3 etc for every cumulative_spend value over 100, but instead I see nulls and the 3 and 4

```
case when cumulative_spend >= 100 then row_number() OVER (partition BY customer_number ORDER BY order_row) end AS transaction_threshold_reached


customer_number    order_date  order_number  spend_amount order_row  cumulative_spend   transaction_threshold_reached
abcdefg            01/01/2023  123456        10.00        1          10.00              null
abcdefg            01/01/2023  123457        50.00        2          60.00              null
abcdefg            14/01/2023  123458        50.00        3          110.00             3
abcdefg            23/01/2023  123459        20.00        4          130.00             4
```

Answer (score 2):

Just subtract the current row's value from the cumulative sum to get sum up to the previous row, and check that it was below 100 while the current row is above 100.

Note that you should use `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` in case of duplicates, and it's also faster.

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date, order_number) AS order_row,
  SUM(spend_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
      ORDER BY order_date, order_number ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as cumulative_spend,
  CASE WHEN spend_amount >= 100
    AND SUM(spend_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
      ORDER BY order_date, order_number ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - spend_amound < 100
       THEN CAST(1 AS bit) END as cumulative_spend_reached_100
FROM YourTable;
```

You can also do this in a CTE or subquery

```sql
WITH summed AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date, order_number) AS order_row,
      SUM(spend_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
          ORDER BY order_date, order_number ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as cumulative_spend
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN spend_amount >= 100
    AND cumulative_spend - spend_amound < 100
       THEN CAST(1 AS bit) END as cumulative_spend_reached_100
FROM summed;
```